# Contiki-OS on MikroeMedia XMega - ATxmega128A1 microcontroller

Tags: atmel, atmega, contiki

Just looked into contiki OS and was wondering is it will work on [MikroeMedia XMega](http://www.mikroe.com/mikromedia/xmega/) - with microcontroller ATxmega128A1??

Comment: Just looked into your question and was wondering if you searched contiki os site deep enough. In 15 seconds I have found a link where it can be seen that not a single XMEGA CPU is supported yet: http://www.contiki-os.org/hardware.html

Comment: I saw that! & thats not deep. I also saw here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997648/gui-library-for-microcontroller that "Besides being a small and elegant operating system for many 8/16/32-bit microcontrollers, it also features a GUI toolkit. It runs on the Atmel AVR!"

Comment: As you can see on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR these are basic AVR families: tinyAVR, megaAVR, XMEGA, Application-specific AVR, FPSLIC (AVR with FPGA), and 32-bit AVRs (AVR32). MEGA and XMEGA are not the same and they are not compatible without code adaptation.