# QML running with Qt for Embedded System on uclinux?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, uclinux, qtwidgets

I only write QML app with Qt 5.1.1 running on Mac & Windows.

Anyone know what's the version of Qt for Embedded System integrated in the uclinux?

Do the Qt on uclinux support QML? Do I need to re-implement the UI with Qt widgets in C++ to run it on the uclinux?

Comment: Isn't uclinux luckily history? Eglibc and glibc are used mostly these days? The last release happened about two years ago. Did that even support STL properly? That is a dependency in Qt these days.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Embedded system. So don't what the options are. If we targeting [LPC1788](http://www.emcraft.com/products/88), any chances we can port QML app to it?

Comment: @lpapp: you are confusing uclibc with uclinux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, please do not ask several subquestions in a question.

> Anyone know what's the version of Qt for Embedded System integrated in the uclinux?

There is no such a thing. Qt 5 is meant to be well supported for embedded, too, without external third-party projects.

That being said, you may ask Digia about their embedded plans, like Boot2Qt and so on.

> Do the Qt on uclinux support QML?

That is the wrong question around. The correct question is whether Qt/QML suppports uclinux. I do not think this will work off-hand, no. You will probably start writing a custom mkspecs file for your scenario and fix lots of issues.

> Do I need to re-implement the UI with Qt widgets in C++ to run it on the uclinux?

That would probably be even worse as they are having a lot of overhead in terms additional layer. What I would suggest is to forget about QML for now, and try to bring up a simple screen with QScreen.

As stated, I do not think even that will work off-hand, but if you are enthusiastic, you could get it work.

Since Qt 5 has a hard dependency on the standard library these days, your first task is to get that building againt your mmu-free uclibc. There was some discussion about that [here](http://www.uclinux.org/pub/uClinux/archive/4884.html).

But honestly, you may be better off with some lightweight gui framework that supports framebuffer for rendering. Qt is big and not properly tested on minimal systems.

Comment: Mind you, Qt does dynamic memory allocation internally, so the best solution would to build your own minimal, statically allocating framework if you ask me, or just get an OS with MMU support if your hardware allows that. I do not know this hardware in question well, but Linux can be put onto minimal systems these days generated by Yocto, buildroot, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Your answer is great! The **lightweight gui framework** you mentioned is like [those mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997648/gui-library-for-microcontroller)?

Comment: @Robert: yes, something along those lines.

Comment: It can be done. See: https://blog.basyskom.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/qtdd2014_qt5_on_a_microcontroller.pdf. If it should be done is a different matter ;-)